# Toggling Classes in bootstrap based on size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that I can toggle certain elements using boostrap's `hidden-*` and `visible-* classes, but I'm looking to do something a bit different.

I'm looking to toggle certain classes on a single control when the size is reduced to a certain point. For example, I have a navigation element that needs to collapse from a vertical list into a horizontal list when `sm` and `xs` are active. Currently, I do it this way:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked hidden-sm hidden-xs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#personalInfo">Personal</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#contactInfo">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">General</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">History</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills visible-sm visible-xs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#personalInfo">Personal </a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#contactInfo">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">General</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">History</a></li>
    </ul>
```

However, maintaining separate lists could be torublesome. Is there anyway to do what I'm after (preferably without javascript)?

Comment: You could use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to change the styling at different break points.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Somewhat, but a bit different. Media queries change the styling, but bootstrap already has the classes I need to make the changes happen, I simply need a certain class to be removed whenever its own media queries kick in.

Comment: Without javascript, you'd have to use media queries and overwrite the styles in the class you'd want removed.  If you didn't mind adding the javascript, you'd set a listener on [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) and page load, check the `.outerWidth()`, and toggle the class as needed.

Comment: While I would love to see this sort of functionality added to Bootstrap; everyone here recommending JavaScript is right.  The framework doesn't support this natively, and while a media query would work it creates redundant code.  JS with a listener on resize/load that intelligently adds or removes `nav-stacked` would be your best option.